# Authenticity of the story that Umar had someone whipped over and over for asking too many questions about Quran?

Tags: hadith, sahaba

I have came across the following story on reddit-

> Subaigh Al-Tamimi began asking Omar by saying: “Tell me about ‘al-dhariat al-dharwa’ [Quran 51:1]”. He said: “They are the winds, and if I had not heard it from the messenger, may God bless him and grant him peace, I would not have told you'', he said: “Tell me about ‘fal-hamelat veqra’ [Quran 51:2] ” He said: “They are the clouds, and if I had not heard it from the messenger, may God bless him and grant him peace, I would not have told you”, he said: “Tell me about the ‘fal-jariat yusra’ [Quran 51:3]” He said: “They are ships, and if I had not heard it from the messenger, may God bless him and grant him peace, I would not have told you” He said: “Tell me about ‘fal-muqassemat amra’ [Quran 51:4].” He said: “They are the angels, and if I had not heard it from the messenger, may God bless him and grant him peace, I would not have told you''.
> So Omar said: “You ask too much”, then he ordered him to be whipped a hundred times and he placed him in a jail. When he recovered, he was whipped a hundred more times. They hit him until he couldn’t stand up. Then they left him until he recovered. Then they returned back to him, then they left until he recovered. Then they left him, then they came back to him. Then Subaigh said: “If you want to kill me, just kill me quickly, and if you want to let me be, then God is merciful.”
> So he exiled him and sent him to Abu Musa al-Ashari and the people of Iraq. They did not allow Muslims to sit with him. If he came to a group of Muslims, they would leave him out. And this became severe for him. So Abu Musa wrote to Omar: “He has repented”, and Omar wrote: “Allow people to sit with him”.

The reference to this was arabic wikipedia - https://ar.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B5%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%BA_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%B9%D8%B3%D9%84

I don't understand arabic so I couldn't verify the reference. Could anyone help me with that?

I did find a [narration](https://ahadith.co.uk/permalink-hadith-2835) that supports the above story -

> Yahya related to me from Malik from Ibn Shihab that al-Qasim ibn Muhammad said that he had heard a man asking ibn Abbas about booty. Ibn Abbas said, "Horses are part of the booty and personal effects are as well." Then the man repeated his question, and Ibn Abbas repeated his answer. Then the man said, "What are the spoils which He, the Blessed, the Exalted, mentioned in His Book?" He kept on asking until Ibn Abbas was on the verge of being annoyed, then Ibn Abbas said, "Do you know who this man is like? Ibn Sabigh, who was beaten by Umar ibn al-Khattab because he was notorious for asking foolish questions." Yahya said that Malik was asked whether someone who killed one of the enemy could keep the man's effects without the permission of the Imam. He said, "No one can do that without the permission of the Imam. Only the Imam can make ijtihad. I have not heard that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, ever said, 'Whoever kills someone can have his effects,' on any other day than the day of Hunayn.”